# How to visualise boundaries created by sklearnIntentClassifier using matplotlib in Rasa

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am using sklearnIntentClassifier in Rasa for intent classification. I want to check how this classifier has built the boundaries for different classes(here intents) using matplotlib with my training data.
I could not see any inbuilt functionality for such task in Rasa.

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

great idea, however calculating the decision boundaries are not always simple. Enabling this is something we're currently working on. Unfortunately, I cannot give a timeline when this feature will become available.